# HashMap java, saving ADSB Messages

Tags: java, class, caching, hashmap, sendmessage

I'm new in java and trying to do my lab exercises. The lab is about ADSB Messages, which I receive in real time. I have to decode the ADSB Message, in order to calculate the latitude, longitude and height of an airplane. My problem is, I don't know, how to save a special Message and use the saved Message in the second step, to calculate my Zone index.
I'm trying to do it with the HashMap class, but it doesn't really save my first received Message.

```
HashMap <String, Object> msgCache = new HashMap <String, Object>();
    Message AdsMsg;
    Message newMsg = new Message ();
    Message oldMsg = new Message ();

    AdsMsg = newMsg;
    AdsMsg = oldMsg;

    if (msgCache.containsKey(ICAO)){
        oldMsg = (Message) msgCache.get(ICAO);

        if (CPRFormat == 1){
            System.out.println("Erhaltene Message ist even ");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Erhaltene Message ist odd ");
        }
    }else{
        System.out.println("ICAO wird gespeichert: " + ICAO);
        msgCache.put(ICAO, newMsg);
    }
```

Comment: I don't know why you are using a HashMap here. You are creating a new HashMap everytime and putting some values there. But, you can directly use the values to calculate your result (assuming j is the result you want).

Comment: I need the HashMap to save my ADSB Messages. I get those Messages every second (it's going through a while loop) and I have to save the first one, to calculate it with the second Message.

Comment: I removed the put, get, containsKey and eq Methods. Didn't really need them, because HashMap already hast them. I also edited my if clause:                                                                                                      Problem is still the same. It doesn't save my received Message with the put Method from HashMap

Comment: The problem is most probably because you are using a wrong key to retrieve the message. Use debugger or add print statements to know whether the value of ICAO is the same while using put, get and containsKey.

Comment: Alternatively, if the key is the same, your HashMap is different each time. I remember that in your original code, you were creating a new HashMap for every request instead of using one populated by the previous request.